# I cannot see the bones in Weight Paint mode

Tags: rigging

How can I see the bones in *Weight Paint* mode? I turned my armature to *Pose Mode*, then *Object Mode*, then *Weight Paint*. But I cannot see the bones in *Weight Paint* mode.

Comment: Please don't use bold text for no reason. As for your question, have you enabled the In Front option for the armature? Please show a screenshot

Comment: The question is phrased as if the bones are only hidden when you switch to _Weight Paint_, are they visible in _Object Mode_? Are you using _Solid_ or _Wireframe_ view? As @moonboots said, screenshots might help.